# What was syntax-begin-function obsoleted in favour of?

Tags: syntax-table, emacs25

Since Emacs 25.1, `syntax-begin-function` is obsolete:

```
syntax-begin-function is a variable defined in ‘syntax.el’.
Its value is nil

  This variable is obsolete since 25.1.
  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
Function to move back outside of any comment/string/paren.
This function should move the cursor back to some syntactically safe
point (where the PPSS is equivalent to nil).
```

This was done in [commit dd1e6846198e559b1c2ca321a1e6f8b05945fd66](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=dd1e6846198e559b1c2ca321a1e6f8b05945fd66) which offers no further explanation how that functionality should be achieved now.  The code also still refers to `syntax-begin-function` in several comments as if nothing happened.

`php-mode` just surrounded the offending code with `with-no-warnings` (cf. https://github.com/ejmr/php-mode/blob/master/php-mode.el#L1193-L1196), and [other projects](https://github.com/ananthakumaran/typescript.el/issues/17) seem to have found no "proper" solution yet either.  The function `php-mode` used for this variable, `c-beginning-of-syntax`, refers to `font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function` which was also removed in Emacs 25.1 (but, again, is referred to in several other comments as well).

If I completely remove the section:

```
  ;; syntax-begin-function is obsolete in Emacs 25.1
  (with-no-warnings
    (set (make-local-variable 'syntax-begin-function)
         'c-beginning-of-syntax))
```

from `php-mode.el` and test it with Emacs 24.3 and 25.2, I don't see any *obvious* adverse effects.

What was `syntax-begin-function` obsoleted in favour of?  Is the reference in `php-mode.el` just dead code that did nothing?  If not, how can I test its behaviour?

Comment: Consider filing a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. The "obsolete" message should indicate what to use instead (IMHO).

Comment: I don't think **@Stefan** would leave out the replacement if there was one, so presumably it's just obsolete. Of course, only he can confirm that. It _is_ strange, though, that [some references](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/d07fd34722b84ae2c407f195c82d7632a94de704/lisp/emacs-lisp/syntax.el#L505-L524) to the now always `nil` `syntax-begin-function` still exists.

Comment: @TianxiangXiong: AFAICT, you are correct.  I'll write up an answer with my findings later (and file a bug).